# Can I use onbeforeunload only when the site is being redirected to a particular website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the onbeforeunload only when the site is being redirected to a particular page. How can I do that?

Comment: Only if that redirect is being done by a user event ( click on link for example) or your own code. Is that the case?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a global variable flag when a link with the appropriate href is clicked.

```
var doUnload = false;

$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
   if(doUnload){
     // whatever it is you want to do
   }
});

$(window).on('click', 'a', function(){
     // parse href for match
     if(this.pathname === '/foo/bar/'){
         doUnload = true;
     }
})
```